# Pizza Database Optimization

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, database-design

that's my first question here, but I've been around for a while.

I want to create a OO/MVC web application (pizza store in php,mysql,codeigniter) where a pizza object is fully customizable.
Every piece of pizza has been designed to be variable, and I'm not sure if the data scheme is optimized, so I'm asking for some advices.

Each **Pizza** is made up of:
**A Crust object**: It can be thin, thick, pan, with grains, etc.
**An Edge object**: It can be thin, thick, filled (can be filled with ONE ingredient), etc.
**A PizzaSize object**: small, medium, large, etc.
**A PizzaLayout object**: 1 flavor, 2 flavors (half-half), 2 flavors (2/3-1/3), etc.
**Observations** string: any user extra option like "raw meat", "toasted onions", etc.
**1 to 4 Flavors**: Flavor 1, Flavor 2, Flavor 3 and Flavor 4. (only Flavor 1 is not nullable)

The **PizzaLayout** object works with an attribute that defines the pizza divisions, for instance:
**"1"** = only one flavor
**"4:4"** = 2 flavors, 4 slices each
**"3:3:3"** = 3 flavors, 3 slices each (that's the only exception to 8 pieces)
**"6:2"** = 2 flavors, one with 6 slices and the other with 2.

For example, if the pizza has an 6:2 layout and the Flavor1 is Bacon and Flavor2 is Mozzarella, so it will have 6 slices of bacon and 2 slices of mozzarella.

Each **Flavor** is made up of an **Ingredient** List (e.g: "*Pepperoni*: cheese, pepperoni, oregano, tomatoes, etc"). The user can change a pizza flavor by changing ingredients individually (e.g. add Bacon to the Pepperoni flavor) or create it's own flavor from scratch.

The pizza store will have pre-configured:

A table of available Crusts.
A table of available Ingredients.
A table of available Layouts.
A table of available Edges. 
A table of available Flavors.
A table of available Sizes.

I'm willing to create a more flexible design where I can add up to 8 different flavors, but I'm not happy with the fixed attributes at Pizza table.
I thought about creating a PizzaLayoutItem, dropping the 4 flavors columns. and each Item has a flavor and number of slices. And each pizza will have a list of Items, so I would create a table:
PizzaLayoutItem: id, pizzaId, flavorId, slices,

So a user defined Ham/Bacon Pizza will have:
A "4:4" layout.
2 LayoutItems, one:  Ham 4 slices. And one: Bacon 4 slices.

My point is, will I have to create all these tables?
Each time the user builds a pizza, the database would query 6 or 7 tables?
We can consider that the table sizes are irrelevant, because the number of crusts, flavors, etc in a pizza store would not be large, so it's a fast query, but still, is there a better way to design this?

I can't post images, so I can't post the scheme I designed =/.

I'm sorry if the layout of this question is not optimized either.

Comment: What's wrong with querying 6 or 7 tables?

Comment: In fact I'd argue that's not enough, that layout string is a horrible approach rather than just storing a list of flavors (with an extra table linking pizza orders to flavors). You're also not storing orders at all (multiple pizzas etc)

Comment: @MarkBaker In fact, I didn't say it's wrong. I'm just asking experienced users if this design is ok or would there be any better one.

Comment: @Blindy Yes, you're right. The string pattern sucks, but the list of flavors is confusing me because in this case, order matters. The user could create a pizza with 4 slices of Ham, 2 of cheese and 2 of  bacon. So if is only an array, then how would we know how much slices of each flavor? That's why I thought about LayoutItems.

Comment: I don't see where the order comes in, if you start counting from the north point you get a different pizza than if you start counting from the east? What if it rotates during transport?

Comment: @Blindy haha. What I meant is that an array of Flavors just tell us what, but not how much. So with an array containing bacon and ham I could build lots of different pizzas. So I need to store the quantity of every flavor. How do I do it the best way? That's the point.

Comment: Another question, whats the best implementation:
Creating a Dao for every entity and a Model that access all Daos or  Creating a "PizzaBuilderDao" that can access all the tables it needs to build a Pizza, and the model just use it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an adjacency list model for the table. It's simple but it also for complex data base scheme like a family tree. Then I would use a decorator pattern for the most of the logic.